# How to add charts to general filter in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have a dataset with multiple columns

How to add individual chart to general filter(NOT IN TEXT AREA) ,i.e if i click F1
then it should show chart1 ,for F2 it should show Chart2 , .... till 10 filters and charts,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "Click F1" are you referencing the function keys on your keyboard or is this a value in a column of your dataset?

Comment: it is value in a column of your dataset

Comment: Are you wanting different types of charts with each selection or just the data to change? Your question isn't very clear.